# Ошибка в Layout в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/gray_50">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTaskTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBotton="16dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvTaskDate"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvTaskDate"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tvTaskDate"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text_default_material_light"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTaskDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_default_material_light"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/cvTaskPriority"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBotton="8dp"
            android:src="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

В Android Studio выходит сообщение:

> No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_marginBotton' in package 'android'

Выше код из Layout файла. Пожалуйста помогите не могу разобраться в чем проблема

Answer (score 3):

Переименуйте

```
marginBotton - > marginBottom
```